# If you are very effective in a leadership position, should you still pursue "being one of many"?

Tags: teamwork, politics, leadership

In a performance review I was told that I was doing excellent job when I was in a specific setting: in charge. In situation when I was in charge of coordinating other people or leading a project, I did great work. But I was told this is not good enough, and I have to stop thinking I should be in charge.
I don't know if this is valid feedback or manipulation.
From my perspective, if I am doing great work in a leadership role, I should be given the leadership role formally, instead of being told "you are one of many, you must work well with others even when you are not in charge."

I want to improve my ability to work with others, but I am also afraid of repressing a natural behaviour which seems to be working well so far.

The question is: if you perform well when you are in charge, should you still pursue being "one of many"?

Answer (score 12):

> From my perspective, if I am doing great work in a leadership role, I should be given the leadership role formally.

From your perspective, sure.

From anyone else's perspective: NO.

If you can't work nicely with others then you are almost certainly not suitable for a leadership position. You might be good at some aspects of the role but a surprisingly large portion of good leadership involves being able to collaborate with your underlings. Lots of bad managers don't understand this and they are uninspiring dismal people who are awful to work for.

Additionally, as others have pointed out, managers/leaders still have peers and it is important that they can work well with those peers.

Comment: Probably important to add that being in charge is not the same as being a leader as this seems to be OPs confusion.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul yes, I think that's a fair point. In order to be a decent manager you need to be a good leader and being a leader has very little to do with being in charge. I'm not sure how to work it into the answer though (without making it overly long/verbose).

Answer (score 6):

> The question is: if you perform well when you are in charge, should you still pursue being "one of many"?

Of course you should. Unless you're the CEO (and realistically, not even then), you're still going to be "one of many", just your peers may be a different group.

> From my perspective, if I am doing great work in a leadership role, I should be given the leadership role formally

Have you asked *why* you haven't been given the leadership role formally, or perhaps more constructively, what you need to do to be given the leadership role formally? Maybe your company needs more "workers in the trenches" and fewer managers right now, maybe something else.

Answer (score 5):

**Being a good teammate is not "repressing your natural leadership", it is *part of* being a good leader**

Being a good leader involves many things. One of them is working well with others.  Unless you own the company, you are not always going to be the one in charge and the one making the decisions.  You may have had success ***so far*** in situations when you were the one in charge, but if you don't work well with others when you are not the one in charge, that won't last.  The people that responded to your leadership will stop doing so once they realize it's a one-way street and you are not going to support them as well.

Answer (score 3):

There's another facet you might be missing: there's a difference between leading and being 'in charge'.

I'm not in charge of my coworkers.  I'll often help lead when we've got a project.

**Leadership isn't about authority or power.**  It's about having a good view of what needs to be done, being able to inspire the people around you towards working towards that goal, and fostering a good atmosphere for those people to work.

**Being in charge isn't about charisma.**  You make decisions, and the people underneath you execute them.

Leadership doesn't require being in charge; being in charge doesn't work well if you can't lead.

So from reading your question, two things are coming through:

- You're conflating being a leader and being in charge.
- Your manager doesn't think you have the ability to *lead*.  You can
  direct people if you have explicit authority... but not if you have
  to work alongside them.

So the answer is: yes, this likely very valuable feedback.  It lets you know that they feel you need to work on your people skills and that they (awesomely) want to make sure that people that move up into management also are leaders instead of just people that can be 'in charge'.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know if this is valid feedback or manipulation

If true, it's very valid and valuable feedback. Possibly aside from the owner of the company, everyone gets to play both a leadership and a coworker role.

Working well with others is an incredibly important skill. Use the constructive criticism to your advantage and learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between being a manager (position), managerial skills (tactical skill set, includes, for example, decision making), and leadership (an interpersonal skill set that helps us look out for each other). Some managers are incredibly skilled leaders, others are not. Some skilled leaders do not occupy a position of authority. The best managers have both strong managerial skills and leadership skills.

You don't make the distinction between skill sets as I have, but let's for the sake of argument say that you are highly skilled in both tactical and interpersonal respects.

> ...if I am doing great work in a leadership role, I should be given the leadership role formally

This is a trap that a lot of people fall into— that you deserve a promotion or position, usually manager, justified by the fact that you have skills. There are a few problems with this thinking.

#### All employees should have some competency in both skill sets

Of course managers need these skills for the group to succeed. But it is incredibly valuable if all workers can make sound decisions, organize their work, etc. and it is extremely valuable if they care enough to help those around them succeed. I would even go so far as to say that leadership skills within the group pay off far more than leadership skills from a manager.

#### It doesn't scale

If you automatically remove employees because of their leadership skill set, where do you put them? You need far fewer managers than other workers. I see the "I deserved a promotion" attitude most among people who have already been promoted a few times and have an expectation that it keep occurring at every opportunity. But there are exponentially fewer positions the higher up the ladder you go.

#### It isn't about you

Hiring a manager is about the success of the group, not the success of the manager. The fact that many managers see their position as a status symbol may be the reason why only [34% of workers are engaged at their job.](https://news.gallup.com/poll/241649/employee-engagement-rise.aspx) Furthermore, this is the company's position to give, not anyone's to take.

---

If I were to read into your question, I would say that perhaps the feedback you received indicated that you are a great tactician, but perhaps lacking in interpersonal leadership skills. I would suggest that, if you'd like to be in a management position, that you work hard to develop skills that help others, and that you *make sure that helping your team is the primary reason you want to be in such a position.*

It sounds like your company works hard to give you and others opportunities to take on those roles in a temporary fashion, which is pretty incredible. It sounds as though they are invested in personal growth of each of you. I would take the advice they give you, both mentioned here and any future advice, to heart.